# Error when presenting a navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

i'm trying to present a navigationController, which seem to work and present the navigationController. However i still keep getting an error even though it works?

**My code**

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AdViewController") as! UINavigationController
let adController = vc.viewControllers.first as! AdViewController
adController.adObject = contentObject
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x1508fea00> on <Kodinh.NewsViewController: 0x1511774a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: This seems unreal. I'm having the exact same issue right now! Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment that you are calling "self.presentViewController", make sure "self" is visible and the warning will go away.